# Android Firebase Recycler view UI inside onDataChange()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (final DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GetModel, RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GetModel, RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
                        (GetModel.class, R.layout.rview, RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder.class, query) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final GetModel model, final int position) {

                        viewHolder.textview.setText(model.getName());
                    }
                };

                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

This code set

> viewHolder.textview.setText(model.getName());

with the last child's name only instead of each child's name.
How to fix this?

Comment: Have you read [https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

Comment: yes,but still getting same result

Comment: You should declare Firebase Recycler outside of `onDataChange()`. Place all of your code outside of it and remove the whole `databaseReference.addValueEventListener(...`. Firebase Recycler handle that automatically, as long as your `query` object is right